# Single Sign On for Sitecore 8.2 platform

Tags: sitecore, single-sign-on, sitecore8, sitecore8.2

We are enabling Single Sign On for Sitecore 8.2 platform. We have used ADFS https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/modules/adfsauthenticator.aspx in the past and it worked fine, but it seems to be on an older version of 7.1.

So we have a specific question that has someone enabled SSO in the latest version of Sitecore 8.2 or 8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to above. So we have Active Directory Module available for latest version also. Active Directory 1.3 works on latest Sitecore Experience Platform 8.2. And Active Directory 1.2 works for Sitecore CMS 7.2 - 8.1.

You can download these versions from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Active_Directory.aspx.